# Как лучше всего записать в текстовый файл?

Tags: c#

Есть метод записи в текстовый файл информации

```
public void RecordLink()
{
    //Обнуляем текстовый файл
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"text.txt", false);         
    int counterNewsLink = 1;

    while (counterNewsLink <= 19) 
    {
        counterNewsLink += 2;

        sw.WriteLine(pageLink.Substring(counterNewsLink + 1));
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

Мне нужно сперва очистить текстовый файл, а затем в него записывать информацию.
Так я его без проблем очищаю.

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"text.txt", false);
```

Но затем выскакивает ошибка, о том ,что он закрыт. Где я не прав ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Закрывать `StreamWriter` нужно после того, как вы закончите с ним работать, т.е. после окончания цикла.
2. Использование `StreamWriter` лучше обернуть в `using`: это позволит отпустить хэндл файла, если во время записи произойдет ошибка. Либо обернуть     код записи в `try/finally` и вызывать `Close()` в блоке `finally`.

```
public void RecordLink()
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"text.txt", false))
    {
        int counterNewsLink = 1;
        while (counterNewsLink <= 19) 
        {
            counterNewsLink += 2;
            sw.WriteLine(pageLink.Substring(counterNewsLink + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Обернуть код записи в try-finally нужно обязательно, ведь файл может быть заблокирован по любой другой причине, не связанной с работой вашего приложения.

Comment: @AnatolyNikolaev и что? Если создание стрима в try выбросит исключение, то и в finally закрывать будет нечего. using уже содержит всю нужную семантику (если не нужна обработка исключений).

Comment: Что значит "если не нужна обработка исключений"? Именно она тут и нужна. Возможно, на finally действительно уже нечего делать (хотя это зависит от задачи), но try - catch нужен однозначно.

Comment: @AnatolyNikolaev это решать автору кода исходя из логики программы, а не нам с вами :). Возможно, в try/catch будет обернут вызов RecordLink(), а возможно, что и вызов выше по стеку.

Comment: @AnatolyNikolaev, вот уж catch тут в общем случае точно не нужен.

Answer (score 3):

Лучше использовать using вместо Close.
А ещё, while замечательно переписывается на for.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"text.txt", false))
  for(int counterNewsLink = 3; counterNewsLink <= 21; counterNewsLink += 2)
    sw.WriteLine(pageLink.Substring(counterNewsLink + 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно просто использовать [File.WriteAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file.writealllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), который сам сделает всю работу:

```
File.WriteAllLines("text.txt", Enumerable.Range(1, 8).Select(i => link.Substring(i*2 + 2)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Вынесите

```
sw.Close();
```

из цикла. Сейчас вы закрываете StreamWriter после первой итерации, и вторая падает с ошибкой что он закрыт.